# How to add a right button to a UINavigationController in a UITabBarController?

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a class that contains a UITabBarController and a UINavigationController (one of the UITabBarController's tabs):

```
 @interface HomeController : NSObject{
UINavigationController *maps;
UIBarButtonItem* national;

}

@property (retain, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (retain, nonatomic) UITabBarController *tabBarController;

@end
```

in the .m file (init method) this is how I'm trying but it doesn't work:

```
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:adminController, maps, sitesController, nil];
```

I want to put the national button as the rightBarButtonItem of my UINavigationController *maps, so I insert that lines on the init methode (.m file):

```
 national= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"national" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:nil action:nil];
    maps.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = national;
    [national release];
```

Because my class isn't a view (sub of NSObject) to insert that code in the viewDidLoad method.

Comment: Did you synthesized your properties?

Comment: I did it inserting that code in the (maps' class)'s viewDidLoad and it worked, I don't delete the Question, cause it can maybe some day help somebody.

Comment: If you figured out the solution, add an answer to your question that explains it.

Answer (score 0):

Maps is not a viewController per se, but its a container object that manages views. At some point the maps has one or more viewControllers - it should always have a rootViewController. So try this:

```
...create and initialize maps
UIViewController *firstView = maps.rootViewController;
firstView.view; // force it to load its view, may or may not be necessary
firstView.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = national;
```